# Facebook Connect login failing after logout, something to do with cookies

Tags: php, facebook, session, cookies

I'm using the PHP SDK for facebook connect.

Now, I can log people in fine using this:

```
# active session
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {
    # Active session,  try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
    try{
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');

    } catch (Exception $e){}

    if(!empty($user)){

GET USER DETAILS FROM DATABASE, SET SESSIONS FOR MY SITE ETC


} else {

        die("There was an error.");
    }
```

However, when I log out of my site (which is just a simple logout script destroying the sessions) and then try to log in again using the same facebook script, it triggers the error, indicating that $user is empty. This happens if I stay logged into facebook or someone else tries it and carries on triggering the error until I clear cookies.

There must be something that I am supposed to clear when I log out or before someone logs in with facebook. But the documentation for Facebook is laughably bad and the forum is a complete shambles.

Note, I do not want to log the user out of facebook, only my site. But I obviously cant have the user have to clear their cookies whenever they want to log back in again.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is searching for this (as the facebook documentation and forum are so absolutely terrible) I just changed the setcookie value to false when you set up your secret key etc.

This means that the user would have to log in again if they left your site, but only if you are not setting your own session/cookie values. So it works perfectly for what I needed.